# JS / jQuery WHILE holding down LMB event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

Im doing some Animation Stuff in jQuery/JS and i want to change my Pull_Push variable depending on wether the LMB(Left Mouse Button) is held down or not.

Now i was looking for an example but found only the .mousedown() and .mouseup() event but they seem to trigger when the Button is pressed / released.
I need a Event between these two. (While holding)

You can check out the [complete Code on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Tibixx/pen/mxRPNQ)

And here is the part i guess i have to fix:

```
var pull_or_push = "push";
$(document).on("mousedown", function () {
    var pull_or_push = "pull";
});
$(document).on("mouseup", function () {
    var pull_or_push = "push";
});
```

Do you see any possible way in achieving what i want?

Comment: What's wrong with using those events?

Comment: the code you have will determine if the mouse button is down, you can just check your `pull_or_push` variable when doing something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to efficiently run code in an interval. Using `setInterval` or `setTimeout` could also work, but `requestAnimationFrame` was made specifically for this kind of thing.

In the following example the `doSomething` function will only start running once mousedown is called and then stop running once mouseup is called. But you can easily make it so that the code is always running by calling your `doSomething` function outside of either of these events. That way, simply by checking the state of `pull_or_push` you can do something while the LMB is pressed and do something else while the LMB is not pressed.

Also note that inside your mouseup and mousedown callbacks you were re-declaring `pull_or_push` instead of modifying the global variable (just remove `var`).

```js
var pull_or_push = "push";
var request;

$(document).on("mousedown", function () {
    pull_or_push = "pull";
    doSomething();

});
$(document).on("mouseup", function () {
    pull_or_push = "push";
    cancelAnimationFrame(request)
});

function doSomething(dt){
  console.log("Doing something")
  request = requestAnimationFrame(doSomething)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Your approach is new to me and i am currently exploring the .requestAnimationFrame() Function, so far the Code works like supposed :) +1 for mentioning my re-declaring mistake